# Python Submodules an easier reference

Tags: python, package

I don't know if this is possible in python but here goes ...

I have a folder structure similar to this

```
\webapplication
    \forms
        __init__.py
        model01.py  # (defines Model01Form)
        model02.py  # (defines Model02Form)
    \views
        __init__.py
        admin.py    # (this file imports the forms)
```

I was wondering if there is any way to import like this but still keep them in separate files.

```
from webapplication.forms import Model01Form, Model02Form
```

Instead of having to do this

```
from webapplication.forms.model01.Model01Form
from webapplication.forms.model02.Model02Form
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only if you import the forms into `__init__.py` in the first place:

```
from model01 import Model01Form
from model02 import Model02Form
```

However, you should ask yourself if you necessarily need to have two separate model files. Python is not Java: you can have as many classes in a module as you like.

Comment: okay ... maybe I should just listen to pyflakes on this one and just define them in a single file forms.py :)

    __init__.py:1: 'OpeningHourForm' imported but unused
    __init__.py:2: 'RestaurantForm' imported but unused

Comment: +1: Why "still keep them in separate files"?  There's little point.

Comment: Multiple files is a perfectly fine way to develop your code. If you have one class per file its real easy to figure out where something is defined. While its ok to put multiple classes in one file tnere is no real advantage (nor disadvantage) in doing so. Do what works best for you and your team.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Doing what works best also means doing what works easily with Python.  When the code is made too complex by a one-class-per-file approach, then perhaps multiple-classes-per-file will work better.  The "easy to figure out" is largely untrue, since most Python folks put multiple classes per file and don't seem to have a problem with it.